# Authentication for composer private repository in composer.json file

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, composer-php, continuous-deployment

I have a composer package in a Gitlab project, and am using the following `composer.json` structure to pull in the package:

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://git.example.com/amarjit/my-package.git"
    }
]
```

Now every time I install a package or do anything using the composer command I have to give credentials for the "my-package" repository. I have created an access token on GitLab with "read only" access to the "my-package" repository and I googled how to use access token with private composer packages, but all of the results suggested saving token in auth.json.

But if I do that then all other developers of the project will also have to do the same in their environment. So Is there any way to save authentication info in composer.json. I know I can put my username and password in the URL attribute inside composer.json. But I don't want to share my creds with other devs.

How I can save the read-only access token in composer.json so that composer doesn't ask for GitLab credentials?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Putting your own credentials to the JSON is bad, as you don't want to share the credentials. Leave them out is bad, as you don't want anybody else to configure this manually - so the question arises: whose account would you like to use otherwise?

Comment: @NicoHaase
I want to save the read-only token in the composer.json file.